# I need to access IOS contacts from within my app.

Tags: ios, url, contacts

There does not appear to be a simple url scheme for contacts like the ones for reminders and calendars. 
Is anyone aware of a scheme to simply call the contact app from swift code?

Comment: Why do you need to launch the Contacts app? The SDK provides all kinds of ways to let a user pick a contact or access contact data without leaving your app.

Comment: That is true and I have code to do that. 
What I want to do is simply open the contacts app from my app.
I have no problem doing this for Reminders, Calendar, sms, email etc. and they all  work really well for my needs, just cannot find the  url for contacts

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the documentation for the Contacts framework, introduced in iOS 9. Documentation and examples can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts).

For instance, you can fetch all contacts containing "Appleseed" in the name with this code:

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Appleseed"), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey])
```

Comment: Thanks - I have code to do what you suggest I was just hoping to open the contact app as I do for reminders, notes etc. 
It seems that for whatever reason there is no url option for contacts.